# Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon Wifi password not saved

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, cinnamon

On a fresh new Cinnamon install I need to re-enter my wifi password after each reboot.

As advised here [How to automatically connect WiFi In Mint 18.3 KDE?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311547/how-to-automatically-connect-wifi-in-mint-18-3-kde) I selected 'Store the password for all users'.

I checked also Automatic connection, but after each reboot no connection, I have to select manually my wifi profile and enter again the password.

Any solution are very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: this sounds like a gnome-keyring failure.. Is there possibly a luks or other kyering interferring?

Comment: not sure to understand, is there something that I can check?